# WordPress - How to create a shortcode that outputs a CPT

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

There are a handful of things I'd like to do with this shortcode I'm working on. My knowledge about this isn't the best, but I'm trying to learn.

```
/**
 * Recent Project Shortcode
 */
function project_query() {
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'post_type'      => 'projects',
        'order'          => 'ASC',
    );
    $projects_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $projects_query->have_posts() ) :
        // var_dump(the_post_thumbnail_url("full")); exit;
        $html_out = '<article class="recent-project" style="background: url(' . $featured_img . ') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;">';
        while ( $projects_query->have_posts() ) :
            $projects_query->the_post();
            // Do stuff with each post here

            $title = get_the_title();
            $link = get_the_permalink();
            $featured_img = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post->ID, 'full' );

            $html_out .= '<h5>Latest Project</h5>' . '<h2>' . $title . '</h2>' . '<a class="btn btn-lg btn-tertiary" href="' . $link . '">' . 'Discover' . '</a>';
        endwhile;
        $html_out .= '</article>';
    else : // No results
        echo "Nothing to show";
    endif;
    wp_reset_query();
    return $html_out;
}
add_shortcode( 'show_project', 'project_query' );
```

There are a few issues here. What does work is that on the front-end it pulls the project name, which is sweet, and the button links to the appropriate page.

Here's how I'd like the shortcode to look when using it: `[show_projects posts_per_page="3" order="ASC"]` I want to make it "easy" for the user to modify the `$args`. The second thing that isn't working is the background url I'm trying to do. Right now in the front end everything is outputting except that background url.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Darren the problem is that you create the `$featured_img` variable after you use it. It should be in `while` loop.

Please try this code

```
/**
 * Recent Project Shortcode
**/
function project_query($atts) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'example_attribute' => 'example_value',
        ),
        $atts, 'example'
    );

    //if you want to use the attribute you should use $atts['example_attribute'] for example

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'post_type'      => 'projects',
        'order'          => 'ASC',
    );
    $posts = get_posts( $args );
    if ( !empty( $posts ) ) :
        $post = array_shift( $posts );
        $title = get_the_title($post->ID);
        $link = get_the_permalink($post->ID);
        $featured_img = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post->ID, 'full'     );

        $html_out = '<article class="recent-project" style="background: url(' . $featured_img . ') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;">';
           // Do stuff with each post here

        $html_out .= '<h5>Latest Project</h5>' . '<h2>' . $title . '</h2>' . '<a class="btn btn-lg btn-tertiary" href="' . $link . '">' . 'Discover' . '</a>';
        $html_out .= '</article>';
     else : // No results
        echo "Nothing to show";
     endif;

     return $html_out;
}
add_shortcode( 'show_project', 'project_query' );
```

Comment: This allows me to get the background img, sweet! How can I extract the parameters so I can use it as atts in the shortcode?

Comment: First you should add the `$atts` parameter to the shortcode function, then you can use it like this `$atts['example_attribute']`. I have edited the code above, so you can use easily use it,